# Effectively handling wildcard characters in Sybase

Tags: sql, wildcard, sybase

I have this query in our legacy application -

`Select * from Customers where Name like ('param')`

Problem is when UI user passes param=%, it shows all available customers. Which we want to avoid.

when `param = [abc]` , it shows all the customers with a,b or c in thier names. We want to avoid this as well.

In fact we want to handle all sort of wild card character searched to avoid SQL Injection.
In java script what is the way I can achieve this, so that I pass only valid Param to my server.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to below query:

```
Select * from Customers where Name like N'%param%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `like`, use `=`:

```
where Name = 'param'
```

`=` is a lot like `like` except it doesn't have wildcards -- That is a bit of a joke.  You don't want wildcards so don't use the operator that relies on them.